# Pyspark 'tzinfo' error when using the Cassandra connector

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm reading from Cassandra using

```
a = sc.cassandraTable("my_keyspace", "my_table").select("timestamp", "vaue")
```

and then want to convert it to a dataframe:

```
a.toDF()
```

and the schema is correctly infered:

```
DataFrame[timestamp: timestamp, value: double]
```

but then when materializing the dataframe I get the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o89372.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 285.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 285.0 (TID 5243, kepler8.cern.ch): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 111, in main
    process()
  File "/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 263, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 541, in toInternal
    return tuple(f.toInternal(v) for f, v in zip(self.fields, obj))
  File "/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 541, in <genexpr>
    return tuple(f.toInternal(v) for f, v in zip(self.fields, obj))
  File "/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 435, in toInternal
    return self.dataType.toInternal(obj)
  File "/opt/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 190, in toInternal
    seconds = (calendar.timegm(dt.utctimetuple()) if dt.tzinfo
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'
```

which sounds like a `string` as been given to `pyspark.sql.types.TimestampType`.

How could I debug this further?

Comment: you didn't by any chance solve this problem?

Comment: @user3688217 Not that I remember, but the connector has been evolving a lot in one year. Do you still have the same issue?

Comment: yeah, I isolated the issue to pyspark.sql instead of the connector. The data frame schema seems to mix up the colums and thus creates this error. But I have no idea how to solve this. this here is my case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42026089/pyspark-createdataframe-string-interpreted-as-timestamp-schema-mixes-up-column

Comment: @user3688217 I won't be able to test it by myself. I suggest you ask Russel on the mailing-list of the connector: https://groups.google.com/a/lists.datastax.com/forum/#!forum/spark-connector-user . In case it is not related to the connector it could be moved up to the Spark Jira I guess.

Comment: @CedricH. I'm having the same issue and not leveraging cassandra at all. Its and issue related to pyspark . I solved it by turning my return into a StringType and then casting to timestamp.