# pyspark createdataframe: string interpreted as timestamp, schema mixes up columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a really strange error with spark dataframes which causes a string to be evaluated as a timestamp.

Here is my setup code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, TimestampType

new_schema = StructType([StructField("item_id", StringType(), True),
                         StructField("date", TimestampType(), True),
                         StructField("description", StringType(), True)
                        ])

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([Row(description='description', date=datetime.utcnow(), item_id='id_string')], new_schema)
```

this gives me the following error:

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([Row(description='hey', date=datetime.utcnow(), item_id='id_string')], new_schema)
>
> /home/florian/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.pyc in
>   createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
>       307         Py4JJavaError: ...
>       308         """
>   --> 309         return self.sparkSession.createDataFrame(data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
>       310 
>       311     @since(1.3)
>
> /home/florian/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.pyc in
>   createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
>       522             rdd, schema = self._createFromRDD(data.map(prepare), schema, samplingRatio)
>       523         else:
>   --> 524             rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(map(prepare, data), schema)
>       525         jrdd = self._jvm.SerDeUtil.toJavaArray(rdd._to_java_object_rdd())
>       526         jdf = self._jsparkSession.applySchemaToPythonRDD(jrdd.rdd(), schema.json())
>
> /home/florian/spark/python/pyspark/sql/session.pyc in
>   _createFromLocal(self, data, schema)
>       397 
>       398         # convert python objects to sql data
>   --> 399         data = [schema.toInternal(row) for row in data]
>       400         return self._sc.parallelize(data), schema
>       401
>
> /home/florian/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.pyc in toInternal(self,
>   obj)
>       574                 return tuple(f.toInternal(obj.get(n)) for n, f in zip(self.names, self.fields))
>       575             elif isinstance(obj, (tuple, list)):
>   --> 576                 return tuple(f.toInternal(v) for f, v in zip(self.fields, obj))
>       577             elif hasattr(obj, "**dict**"):
>       578                 d = obj.**dict**
>
> /home/florian/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.pyc in ((f, v))
>       574                 return tuple(f.toInternal(obj.get(n)) for n, f in zip(self.names, self.fields))
>       575             elif isinstance(obj, (tuple, list)):
>   --> 576                 return tuple(f.toInternal(v) for f, v in zip(self.fields, obj))
>       577             elif hasattr(obj, "**dict**"):
>       578                 d = obj.**dict**
>
> /home/florian/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.pyc in toInternal(self,
>   obj)
>       434 
>       435     def toInternal(self, obj):
>   --> 436         return self.dataType.toInternal(obj)
>       437 
>       438     def fromInternal(self, obj):
>
> /home/florian/spark/python/pyspark/sql/types.pyc in toInternal(self,
>   dt)
>       188     def toInternal(self, dt):
>       189         if dt is not None:
>   --> 190             seconds = (calendar.timegm(dt.utctimetuple()) if dt.tzinfo
>       191                        else time.mktime(dt.timetuple()))
>       192             return int(seconds * 1e6 + dt.microsecond)
>
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tzinfo'

this looks as if a string was passed to TimestampType.toInternal()

the really weird thing is that this data frame creates the same error:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([Row(description='hey', date=None, item_id='id_string')], new_schema)
```

while this one works:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([Row(description=None, date=datetime.now(), item_id='id_string')], new_schema)
```

and this one works as well:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([Row(description=None, date=datetime.now(), item_id=None)], new_schema)
```

For me, this now means that the pyspark somehow puts the value from "item_id" into the column "date" and therefore creates this error.
Did I do something wrong? Is this a bug within data frames?

info:
I am using pyspark 2.0.1

Edit:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([Row(description=None, date=datetime.now(), item_id=None)], new_schema)
df.first()
```

> Row(item_id=u'java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=false,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Etc/UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=?,YEAR=2017,MONTH=1,WEEK_OF_YEAR=?,WEEK_OF_MONTH=?,DAY_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_YEAR=?,DAY_OF_WEEK=?,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=?,AM_PM=1,HOUR=3,HOUR_OF_DAY=15,MINUTE=19,SECOND=30,MILLISECOND=85,ZONE_OFFSET=?,DST_OFFSET=?]',
>   date=None, description=None)

Answer (score 12):

When you create a Row object, the fields are sorted alphabetically (http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Row), so when you are creating the `Row(description, date, item_id)` object, it will be ordered as  `(date, description, item_id)`.

As your schema is ordered as `StringType, TimestampType, StringType`, when creating a DataFrame with this Row and schema, Spark will map what is in `date` to a `StringType`, what is in `description` to a `TimestampType` and `item_id` to a `StringType`.

Passing a Timestamp (in `datetime` format) to a `StringType` does not cause an error, but passing a String to a `TimestampType` does, since it asks for the `tzinfo` attribute, which, as the error stated, the String object does not has it.

Also, the reason the dataframes that worked for you actually worked is because `None` is being passed to the `TimestampType` in your schema, which is an acceptable value.

Comment: I had this same problem.  Simply reordering the schema definition fields to be listed in alphabetical order as mentioned above resolved the problem for me.

Comment: Thank you!  This has been driving me nuts

Answer (score 6):

Basing this off of the answer above from @rafael-zanetti. You can do the following to sort your columns:

```
new_schema = [StructField("item_id", StringType(), True),
                     StructField("date", TimestampType(), True),
                     StructField("description", StringType(), True)]
new_schema = StructType(sorted(new_schema, key=lambda f: f.name))
```